# Anyway to Re-define or Re-use the same variable

Tags: android

I'm new with android and not familiar with JAVA.

Situation:
i have few imageview work as button (will increase phase by phase)
so i'm thinking a way to re-use the same variable for those "Buttons"

what i wish to do is, no matter the user click on which button, i will reset all the button default setting, then only set on the clicked button setting.

because the "buttons" with keep adding in future so i hope NOT to define each on every button.....

hope you guys can understand my question, and here is the screen

[image]

the clicked one (button) with set image show to  "xxx_on" and tag set "xxxon" as well.

Comment: declare ImageView iv globally i.e outside the method and learn about global and local variables in java

Comment: following @JiiN Wee your way achieving what you said might become difficult if the number of buttons/imagevies increases. instead try inflating/generate the same buttons repeatedly using loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't **declare** variable more than once, but you can **define** it all the times you want.

```
ImageView iV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_job);
//do something
iV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_chat);
//do more stuff
iV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_more);
//do more more stuff
```

In the first line, you declare and define (give a concrete value) the varible. Next times you only need re-define it, not re-declare.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to redefine ImageView object. Define it one time and use it multiple times:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_job);
//Do some thing with iv
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_chat);
//Do some thing with iv
```